# flatten a nested list by using generator

Tags: python, generator

I write the exmple code in **9.7.1 Create Generator** of the book, *[Beginning Python From Novice to Professional(Third Exdition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484200292)*

But I did not output what the output should be in the book.

example in the book:

```py
def flatten(nested):
    for sub in nested:
        for element in nested:
            yield element

nested = [[1,2],[3,4],[5]]

for num in flatten(nested):
    print(num)
```

The output in the book:

```py
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
```

my output with python 3.7.2:

```
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
[5]
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
[5]
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
[5]
```

what's wrong with my python???

Comment: You have a typo. You want `for element in sub`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third line should be `for element in sub:`

```
def flatten(nested):
    for sub in nested:
        for element in sub:  # typo was here
            yield element

nested = [[1,2],[3,4],[5]]

for num in flatten(nested):
    print(num)
```